# Join 2 dataframes with a startdate and enddate column

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to know how I can join data from a definition table with a start and end date column in to my event table with a date column where the date column is between the startdate and enddate columns.

Ex:

```
Table A: Columns = [Date, Reading]
Table B: Columns = [StartDate, EndDate, Amount]
```

In SQL I would do the following:

```
Select Date, Reading, Amount From
    A Join B on B.StartDate <= A.Date and B.EndDate > B.Date
```

I tried creating a function that would filter on table B and then using apply like below.

```
def find(d):
    r = B[(B['StartDate'] <= d['Date']) & (B['EndDate'] > d['Date'])]['Amount']        
    if r.count()>0:
        return r.index[0]
    return 0

A['Amount'] = A.apply(find, axis=1)
```

This works but it is extremely slow, as my event table is about 20MB in size.

Thank you

Comment: Can you show a small sample of tables `A` and `B`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a dummy data set with 40K rows in `A` and 100 rows in `B`, the following
approach is about 1000x faster than using `.apply` with the provided function.

Assuming B looks like the following frame,

```
>>> B
   StartDate    EndDate  Amount
0 2000-01-01 2000-01-16      10
1 2000-02-01 2000-02-16      20
2 2000-03-01 2000-03-16      30
3 2000-04-01 2000-04-16      40
4 2000-05-01 2000-05-16      50
         ...        ...     ...

[100 rows x 3 columns]
```

B can be translated, as shown below, into a TimeSeries with an index that
contains every day defined by the ranges of B and the corresponding 'Amount'
value.

```
def make_series(start, end, amount):
    idx = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='D', closed='left')
    return pd.Series([amount] * len(idx), index=idx)

def make_series2(s):
    idx = pd.date_range(s['StartDate'], s['EndDate'], freq='D', closed='left')
    return pd.Series([s['Amount']] * len(idx), index=idx)

# for non-overlapping ranges
>>> B2 = pd.concat([make_series(s, e, a) for _, s, e, a in B.itertuples()])

# for overlapping ranges
>>> B2 = B.apply(make_series2, axis=1).bfill().T[0]

>>> timeit B2 = pd.concat([make_series(s, e, a) for _, s, e, a in B.itertuples()])
100 loops, best of 3: 15.9 ms per loop
>>> timeit B2 = B.apply(make_series2, axis=1).bfill().T[0]
10 loops, best of 3: 54.9 ms per loop

>>> B2
2000-01-01    10
2000-01-02    10
...
2008-04-14    1000
2008-04-15    1000
Length: 1500
```

The final step is to index into `B2` using `A.Date`:

```
>>> A['Amount'] = B2[A.Date].fillna(0).values

>>> timeit A['Amount'] = B2[A.Date].fillna(0).values
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.91 ms per loop
```

For comparison, here's the timeit of `apply` on the same frames:

```
>>> timeit A.apply(find, axis=1)
1 loops, best of 3: 26.3 s per loop
```